# centering :after border to end of container?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

How to make `:after` border reach the end of the container using plain css or Tailwind?
Ideally filling the remaining space as in image2 below. Currently, my width is 5rem, flexbox seems ideal, but I can't get it to work.

```css
.subheading:after {
  background-color: rgb(194, 188, 178);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.subheading:after {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
    <h1 class="subheading">Coronovirus</h1>
</section>
```

**Image1**

[image]

**Image2**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some ligns to your css:

- Set `h1` as `display:flex` and did some align adjustment
- Add the `:after` added `flex: 1 1 auto;`

```css
.subheading:after {
  background-color: rgb(194, 188, 178);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.25rem;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.subheading:after {
  margin-left: 20px;
  /* ADDED */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

/* ADDED */
h1{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
    <h1 class="subheading">Coronovirus</h1>
</section>
```